# A modern approach to gauge theories; book reference

Tags: resource-recommendations, gauge-theory

First of all, I realize this question has been asked multiple times on this site, however most threads are quite old. I am seeking references which aim to teach and review gauge theory with a modern approach. Some of the most notable texts recommended in previous threads are;

1. Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity (J. Baez and J. Muniain, 1994)
2. Geometry, topology and physics (M. Nakahara, 2003)
3. Fields (W. Siegel, 1999)

I agree that each of these texts look like solid learning material (I have not yet committed to any of them yet, though), but they are quite old (20 years or so) and I constantly hear/read that the subject is always rapidly advancing. Are these books still the best out there to learn gauge theory, or are there newer resources which take a more modern pedagogical approach? (bonus points if it covers higher-spin and topological field theories).

Comment: If you have reason to believe the answers to another question are outdated, the proper procedure is to offer a bounty with the "current answers are outdated" reason instead of duplicating the question.

Comment: Duly noted, apologies for the naivety.

Comment: May we keep this thread so I can link it in the bounty 'custom message'?